# Is there a safe alternative to striptags in Jinja?

Tags: python, escaping, jinja2, code-injection, pelican

I noticed this behaviour while using [pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com):

```
Template('<p>{{text|striptags|striptags}}</p>').render(text='&lt;script src="http://chezsoi.org"/&gt;')
```

is getting rendered as:

```
<script src="http://chezsoi.org"/>
```

I was counting on `striptags` output to be free of any HTML tag, which is false.
Hence my question: is there a "safer" alternative to the builtin `striptags` filter ?

I know that a quick solution is to chain calls to `striptags`:

```
'{{ <p>text|striptags|striptags|striptags }}</p>'
```

But in case an attacker has control over `text` content, they can double-HTML-escape the string, and so on and so on.

Comment: What version are you seeing this on? With `Jinja2-2.9.6` your first example errors out for me with `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'`, and when removing the surrounding `<p/>`, the template expansion results in the empty string (script tags successfully recognized and stripped).

Comment: Hmm, seeing the same behavior you described when I reduce the two chained `striptags` to simply one. Either way, I think in terms of security (XSS), the way to go is to use [autoescaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#autoescaping) and only turn it off specifically where you need to actually inject markup built from safe / already sanitized input.

Comment: I'm using Jinja2 v2.9.6
The `<p>` was initially misplaced in my example, I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the `striptags` filter is intended for "aesthetical" removal of tags (cleaning data to get pure plain text), but not as a water tight security measure.

---

In terms of security (preventing XSS), you should use [Jinjas HTML escaping features](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#html-escaping).

You can either manually escape HTML using the `|escape` filter (alias: `|e`), or use an `Environment` and turn on Jinja's **[autoescaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#autoescaping)**:

```
>>> env = Environment(autoescape=True)
>>> template = env.from_string('<p>{{text}}</p>')

>>> template.render(text='<script src="http://chezsoi.org"/>')
u'<p>&lt;script src=&#34;http://chezsoi.org&#34;/&gt;</p>'

>>> template.render(text='&lt;script src="http://chezsoi.org"/&gt;')
u'<p>&amp;lt;script src=&#34;http://chezsoi.org&#34;/&amp;gt;</p>
```

See also the [Security Considerations](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/security/) section in the Flask docs - Flask turns on Jinja's autoescaping for that reason, to prevent XSS.

---

Also Jinja will [likely make autoescaping the default](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/) in the future:

> **Autoescaping**
>
> [...] However autoescaping is not yet enabled by default though this will most likely change in the future
>
> **Notes on Autoescaping**
>
> In future versions of Jinja2 we might enable autoescaping by default for security reasons. As such you are encouraged to explicitly configure autoescaping now instead of relying on the default.

Comment: This is a good idea, and doable in pelican by setting: `JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {'trim_blocks': True, 'lstrip_blocks': True, 'autoescape': True}`
But sadly because it not the default in pelican, the theme templates I use completely break when I enable this :(
I guess I'll have to manually `|escape`

Comment: That's a pity :-( But since Jinja will likely move to turn on autoescaping by default in the future (see my updated answer), chances are the `pelican` (theme) developers might at some point update their templates accordingly. Thanks for the pointer regarding the manual `|e[scape]`, included that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pelican does not enable Jinja's `autoescape` by default (as for now, version 4.5.1), which in my opinion is not a good idea. Article's title and summary should not contain chars like `<` `>`, or you won't get a correct output result. For theme coders, it is not convenient, and prone to bugs. In fact, only few variables should be output as what it is, most variables should be encoded when output.

You can enable it in your config file:

```py
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {
    'autoescape': True,
}
```

And don't forget to modify your template accordingly. Remove filters like `striptags` and `escape` to avoid double-escaping, and add `safe` filter to some output point where should not do escaping:

```
{{ article.content | safe }}
```

If you are not sure, keep an original vesion of generated static files, and compare with it later to see what is changed.

Comment: While I agree with this approach, beware that the majority of themes will break and some work will be required to convert them to support `autoescape` (I am currently working on my custom theme conversion to support `autoescape` and it is tough :) )